# Iframe aspect ratio 16:9 with fixed height

Tags: html, iframe, bootstrap-4

I am trying to include a YouTube video in my website, but i am struggeling to get an aspect ratio of 16:9 on my iframe.
My problem is, I am working with a fixed height, but am flexible in my width. As this is a rather unusual case, I cannot seem to find a solution to my problem in any documentations, or on other StackOverflow questions.
Those all have a fixed width, and are then using padding-bottom: 56,25%; to fith the height.

I am using bootsrap classes to style my HTML, but I still apply a style tag here and there, to customize the design, that is why the code I have included below might seem a bit messy.
Next to the iframe (right side) there should be another div element, which is marked in the code with the id="text-next-to-iframe"

I have tried using said method of including a specific padding in a div surronding my iframe, and then setting the width and height of the actual iframe to 100% as you would do in a fixed height cenario, but that did not work.
I have also tried to set my iframe height to 29vh (the height I need it to be) and setting the width to different vw-values (trying to find the right value), but I ended up with the iframe not showing at all with both methods.

```
<body style="height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="container-fluid float-md-right mt-2" style="max-width: 79%; height: 100vh;">
        <div class="d-flex float-left mt-2 col-md-9" style="height: 29vh; border: 1px solid black;">
            <iframe id="YTPlayer" height="100%" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>Video wird geladen...</iframe>
            <div id="text-next-to-iframe">  
                <h2>
                    <img alt=" " src="./includes/images/BAUMorg.png" style="width: 10%;"/>
                    BAUMorg
                </h2>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-HWN5WLWQPPIHB3dwQ9atQ?sub_confirmation=1" role="button" target="_blank" style="width: 10vw; font-size: 25px; align: center;">
                    <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>
                    Subscribe
                </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: If you have a fixed height and a flexible width... the wider you get the flatter the object. Are you sure you are aware of your layout's capabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I didn't misunderstand this question but hopefully, this will help.

To configure the aspect ratio you want to divide the screen or container width by 16 and multiply that result by 9 to get your height.

screenWidth = containerWidth / 16

screenHeight = screenWidth * 9

Vh is relative to 1% of the viewport, and you said you need 29vh for your height. So we need to do this in reverse to get the opposite (width).

screenHeight = 29vh

screenWidth = (screenHeight / 9) * 16

which is equal to 51.5 if we drop the trailing 5's and round up it is 52vh.

Hope this helps.

```
<style>
iframe{
      width: 52vh;
      height: 29vh;
    }
</style>

<iframe id="YTPlayer"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t2ByLmLnYJ8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```